# Get all combinations from list with and without repeat

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

How I can get all combinations with repeat and without them from this list.
Final output will be:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Comment: Info: This is called permutations. You can search it on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(itertools.permutations(a))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `permutations` function from `itertools`

```
from itertools import permutations
x = list(itertools.permutations(a))
```

The above list will not be lexicographically sorted. If the given input list is sorted, then the output list will be sorted. Else you have to manually sort the list using `x.sort()`